# Are there any differences between "baby" vegetables and their "regular" counterparts

Tags: vegetables

I'm referring to vegetables like baby carrots, baby spinach, baby cucumber, etc.  Supermarkets sell quite a few "baby" varieties of vegetables and they seem to be priced more expensive per ounce than their "regular" counterparts.

Am I naive thinking that (for instance) baby carrots are simply carrots harvested early?  Or are they a different kind of carrot, just small?

I'm looking for nutritional as well as culinary differences.  For instance, if a recipe calls for a "baby" vegetable, can you substitute it for a finely chopped regular vegetable?

Comment: Eating babies..oh the humanity!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talking about nutritional value on here can be [tricky](http://www.whfoods.com/genpage.php?tname=dailytip&dbid=265), because this site about cooking

> Are baby carrots are simply carrots harvested early? Or are they a different kind of carrot, just small?

Yes they are harvested earlier, or even grown more closely. However nowadays they have developed miniature strains which are mature when small in stature. [This page](http://www.carrotmuseum.co.uk/babycarrot.html) contains lot of information about baby carrots, an even a [video](http://www.youtube.com/v/lNy948H2ta4), so you can try growing this in your garden.

Baby carrots are not as nutritious as full whole carrots, because a lot of the goodness in carrots is contained in the skin and just below it. This is removed in the baby carrot making process. A pack of baby carrots look more aesthetic and they are more tender/sweeter, that is a selling point.

Comment: Your answer  does a great job at explaining botanical differences and similarities, but I'd like to add some more culinary information: In the cases where "baby" does actually refer to younger versions of the same plant, you often have a more tender structure / texture (e.g. in baby spinach the stems are less hard, because they have had less time to harden out) and a milder flavour (see again baby spinach, where the flavours have had less time to become sharp over time).

Comment: Sure @ErikP you can edit your contribution, or if it is lot of content, you can post it as your own answer :)

Comment: Actually that was all I had as additional content - which I felt was a little thin to serve as a full answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

> Baby carrots are [not young carrots](http://www.wisebread.com/baby-carrots-the-frugal-idea-that-isnt), but rather small pieces of carrots that are chopped and whittled down to [look like small carrots](http://www.snopes.com/food/tainted/carrots.asp).